# REST API: How to create or update attachment in a list item?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to attach a file to a list item in Sharepoint 2013.
If an attachment with the same name already exists, I need to overwrite its content with the new one.

I'm currently using request like this:

```
.../AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='MyFile.csv')
```

It works if no attachment with the same name exist in the item.
But it fails if attachment already exists.
Is there a way to instruct SP to overwrite the attachment when it's already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, overwrite is not possible with REST but you can delete and re-attach it.
See [this Stack Exchange post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/203548/43791).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about this, but give it a try :D

```
.../AttachmentFiles/add(overwrite=true, FileName='MyFile.csv')
```

Comment: I've tired this, it doesn't work with attachments unfortunately.